# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null - Adding class to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, console.log

Reworking some old code for a project i need to resubmit and wrote this almost 6 months ago so i cant even remember much and i struggle with JS.

I have a onclick function that adds the class current to my html, it is a popup message for a user and when they click exit it removes the popup button, But looking now in my console it is give out an error of `script.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') at script.js:13:19`

This code does work fine but i cant have console errors for my project.

This is the javascript function that adds and removes the class current.

```
const quizStart = document.querySelector('.quiz-btn');
const quizPopup = document.querySelector('.start-quiz-popup');
const quizMain = document.querySelector('.main');
const quizExit = document.querySelector('.exit-btn');

// Add current tag for onclick targetting
quizStart.onclick = () => {
    quizPopup.classList.add('current');
    quizMain.classList.add('current');
};

// Remove current tag for onclick targetting
quizExit.onclick = () => {
    quizPopup.classList.remove('current');
    quizMain.classList.remove('current');
};
```

The popup is set to have opacity of 0 and then when the current tag is added to the class, another css element of .main.current has opacity to 1.

Before

```
<section class="main"></section>
<div class="start-quiz-popup"></div
```

After

```
<section class="main current"></section>
<div class="start-quiz-popup current"></div
```

I have looked at other guides and asked a couple people but they are not to sure, I struggle with javascript alot and not sure what is wrong when its working fine. This is a old project that i need to completly rework and have had to make alot of changes and more to come, html and css are fine but looks like i need to rewrite alot of css as originally followed a guide and was all built on one page, but it had 0 responsivness as i didnt know how to do all of that with the way it was setup.

It probably is very basic code but i just cant figure it out or what the best way to go about making a updated version. I have tried a couple examples but it just replaces my current tag in place rather than adding the "current" tag maybe the word "active" would be better so future i'll use thaat, just need to get it working without a console error. Apoligies if this is so simple, im just stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where exactly have you imported your script?

If the script has been imported at the top of the HTML without the `async` or `defer` attribute, it will instantly start executing before the HTML is parsed and rendered, therefore causing the above error.

Check your script import.

Comment: the script is at the bottom of the page, I have added a defer attribute to the script tag and the error is no longer there. The issue is still showing on the quiz page, so have HTML for the preview and on the popup button, the user can read the rules and click continue or exit. If continue they are take to the main quiz page to answer the question.

It fixed the issue on the home page, but I'm guess that because those tags are not there on the quiz page it cant see so returns null? do I split the script up and have a new file just for the adding current tag?

Comment: If you have a separate HTML file for the quiz page, i would recommend using a separate script to manage the quiz page.

Comment: Okay thank you, so just have the on click class list add for the home page as its own script and then on the quiz page have its own script file for all quiz stuff. Thank you